# Angular JS clears the text box on scope data change

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use interval data update in my angular project. However when the timeout executes, it clears the text boxes that have some thing filled in them. I tried to replicate this on plunker but it works fine on the plunker. Here's the plunker (which works as I expected)

https://embed.plnkr.co/0RqJMa/

A similar code on my project is clearing the field. What could be the reason? Let me know if more info needs to be added.

Here's my code that kind of does a similar thing as the plunker. `init()` is the method executed initially when the controller is in the current scope.

```
var init = function () {
        $scope.user_mentee_exercises = PageConfig.boardJson.mentoring_tracks;
        $scope.user_exercises = PageConfig.boardJson.learning_tracks;

        switch ($scope.subnav.active) {
            case 'All':
                $scope.sections.data = $scope[$scope.active_tab];
                break;
            default:
                $scope.sections.data[$scope.subnav.active] = $scope[$scope.active_tab][$scope.subnav.active];
                break;
        }

        $timeout(function () {
            BoardServices.board_data()
                .success(function (response) {
                    PageConfig.boardJson.mentoring_tracks = response.mentoring_tracks;
                    PageConfig.boardJson.learning_tracks = response.learning_tracks;

                    init();
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }, 40000);
    };
```

Comment: is it not working in your post and works in plnkr??

Comment: Yeah it works on plunker but not in my actual code. Note that this is a replication code not the original

Comment: How are we supposed to help you fix something if we only see code that works...?

Comment: @LucasWatson I updated the question with the code

Comment: Try pulling the $timeout function out of the init() function. Also note that timeout will only be called once, unlike your plnkr which uses interval.

Comment: Timeout calls init again. It will basically do what interval does. I read through a few questions on stackoverflow suggesting to use this way instead of interval